# What's the wrong with making the ApplicationCookie SameSite=Strict in IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, security, cookies, identityserver4, samesite

I'm developing an `IdP` with `IdentityServer4`, and everything works fine, but now from the security perspective, I want to make it as secure as I can; So I made all cookies `SameSite` as `Strict`, and after that, I got `HTTP error code 400` in situation below:

- User `TestUser` opens the client app `A`
- `TestUser` signed in to the client app `A`
- `TestUser` signed out from the client app `A`
- `TestUser` is trying to log into the client app `A` again (he/she hits the login button in the client app `A`)
- at this point, the `TestUser` redirects to my `IdP`'s login page but receives only the `HTTP 400 error code` and no other details are displayed to check the status.

And here are my cookies:
[image: My cookies]

And my configuration:

```
// Identity Cookie (Authentication cookie)
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // options.Cookie.Name = ..... 
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
    options.SlidingExpiration = false;

    // without expire time ~> session cookie. destroy after closing the browser
    // options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000);
    // options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
});
```

And as you can see, `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` (application cookie) cookie is set to be `SameSite=Strict`. If the `SameSite` set to be `Lax`, everything works fine, but what is the matter with `SameSite=Strict`in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

In short because IdentityServer4 (and any OpenID Connect provider for that matter) relies on HTTP redirects between different sites and cookie authentication for the OIDC endpoints themselves. SameSite=Strict is inherently incompatible with the duties the primary authentication cookie has to perform unless all clients live within the same site (according to the SameSite rules of what constitutes "same site").

When you move from client.x.com -> idp.y.com that's a non-SameSite navigation so any Strict cookies for idp.y.com will be blocked by the browser.

Having SameSite=None is OK however provided you have comprehensive CSRF protection on all of your cookie-secured endpoints. Note that `idsrv.session` must be SameSite=None as it is used by the session monitoring endpoint which is loaded inside an iframe within the client application.

You can see this behaviour if you inspect the request cookies in the developer tools - it will indicate blocked cookies with a warning triangle and explain the reason in the tooltip.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got it about `ApplicationCookie`. But is it ok for `idsrv.session` cookie to be `Lax`? And should I concern about `XSS attacks` or other issues?

Comment: idsrv.session would need to be None too since it’s used inside an iframe. If not intending to use that feature it’s not something to worry about. You’ll need to implement your own CSRF protection for any non-identityserver4 endpoints but ASP.Net Core has decent suppport for that.